# how to create a symfony query > date

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i'm trying to do a query that find entity of this year .

i try this but don't work

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT p
            FROM AppBundle:Analisi p
            WHERE p.dataCreazione > :current_year
            ORDER BY p.dataCreazione ASC'
        )->setParameter('current_year', date("Y").'01-01');
   $analisi = $query->getResult();
```

it return analisi in database. It don't work but i don't understand why

Comment: Can you show your error?

Answer (score 4):

try with one more minus symbol as: `date("Y").'-01-01')`

```
   ->setParameter('current_year', date("Y").'-01-01');
```

more readable way could be:

```
       $date= date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of january this year'));


  $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT p
            FROM AppBundle:Analisi p
            WHERE p.dataCreazione > :current_year
            ORDER BY p.dataCreazione ASC'
        )->setParameter('current_year', $date);
```

Hope this help